# Updating controller variable at set interval

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I currently have the following simple controller:

```
class SimpleController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @results = fetch_results
  end
end
```

`fetch_results` is a fairly expensive operation so although the above works, I don't want to run it every time the page is refreshed.  How can I decouple the updating of `@results` so that it's updated on a fixed schedule, let's say every 15 minutes.

That way each time the page is loaded it will just return the current `@results` value, which at worst would be 14 minutes and 59 seconds out of date.

Comment: Store the result in a db table and additionally a timestamp which is checked before the time expensive op is done. If the timestamp is older than 15 minutes, do the operation, otherwise use the cached result from the database.

Comment: Can you post your `fetch_results` code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might want to use Rails` [low level caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#low-level-caching) for this:

```
def index
  @results = Rails.cache.fetch('fetched_results', expires_in: 15.minutes) do
    fetch_results
  end
end
```

Read more about how to [configure Rails' caching stores](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#cache-stores) in the Rails Guide.

Answer (score 1):

Well I would store this in a **database** **table** and update regularly via a [**background job**](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq). The updates will be relative to some events, like if the user has done something that may change the result, then the result will be recalculated and updated.

Another solution is to update the `result` regularly, say every hour, using **cron jobs**. There is a good [**gem**](https://github.com/javan/whenever) that can handle it.